# Can't unescape double quotes in JSON object POST with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

I am trying to POST JSON, but the `"` is coming through escaped as `%22`. So where I see this: `{%22domain%22:%22asdf.com%22,%22playerClass%22:%22asdf%22,%22adTag%22:%22%22}` in the console after POSTing, I want to send it without the double quotes being escaped. So, it should look like this: `{"domain":"asdf.com","playerClass":"asdf","adTag":""}`

I am looping through the form fields like so:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

And storing the result like this:

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());
```

How can I unescape the `"` from becomeing `%22`? The correct format is showing up in the result div, but the console log shows the escaped characters in the JSON object.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sfbvhLz5/1/)**

Comment: Doesn't JQuery let you ajax-send a form without manually serializing it yourself? Can't recall the function though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the data as part of the url argument which jQuery further treats as a URIcomponent, and escapes.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "?" + dataString,
...
```

Instead, you should pass this as data, then handle it on your server as a part of the form post:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "?"
            data: dataString,
```

Then jQuery won't escape it thinking that it is a URI. Of course, you actually don't need to stringify that data yourself! Just pass in the native JS object and JQuery will stringify it for you. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings.